# xbrl us gaap contextRef standard?

Tags: xml, parsing, standards, accounting, xbrl

Please tell me this is standardized, or at least there is some way to decipher it.

I'm looking at these 3 random 10-Qs and Ks from 2012Q4.

1. ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1001288/0001001288-12-000041.txt
2. ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1002037/0001193125-12-506687.txt
3. ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1002360/0001000096-12-000199.txt

The line items are standardized; however, there are many of them per document.  For instance, one document will have a few `us-gaap:OperatingIncomeLoss`es, and the only way I can tell that they denote which period they are reporting is with `contextRef`.  That's where things get complicated.

I see no discernible pattern.  Sometimes they're ascending then descending.  They all have their own date formats.  Some do multi-period grouping.  Some don't.

I've tried to find a standard on this.  No go.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Gracchus are you from Greece?

Comment: Dear Roman have you found a way to discern the contextRef? I am struggling here... I have found that the `contextRef` is somehow connected to an element called `context` on the bottom of the XBRL Instance document but i havent been able to understand how this actually works.... any help will be pure gold!!! BTW that shield on your logo is Lakedaimonian from Sparta

Comment: Oh and a slight detail...it weights 90 - 100 pounds...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

its in `xbrl 2.1 specification` 
 http://www.xbrl.org/Specification/XBRL-RECOMMENDATION-2003-12-31+Corrected-Errata-2005-04-25.htm#_4.6.1

```
      <context id="BalanceAsOf_20120531">
        <entity>
          <identifier scheme="http://www.sec.gov/CIK">0000866729</identifier>
        </entity>
        <period>
          <instant>2012-05-31</instant>
        </period>
      </context>
      <context id="BalanceAsOf_20120531_AccumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeMember">
        <entity>
          <identifier scheme="http://www.sec.gov/CIK">0000866729</identifier>
          <segment>
            <xbrldi:explicitMember dimension="us-gaap:StatementEquityComponentsAxis">us-gaap:AccumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeMember</xbrldi:explicitMember>
          </segment>
        </entity>
        <period>
          <instant>2012-05-31</instant>
        </period>
      </context>
      <unit id="USD">
        <measure>iso4217:USD</measure>
      </unit>
    <us-gaap:AssetsCurrent contextRef="BalanceAsOf_20120531" unitRef="USD" decimals="-5">929900000.0</us-gaap:AssetsCurrent>
    <us-gaap:Assets contextRef="BalanceAsOf_20120531" unitRef="USD" decimals="-5">1670300000.0</us-gaap:Assets>
    <us-gaap:StockholdersEquity contextRef="BalanceAsOf_20120531_AccumulatedOtherComprehensiveIncomeMember" unitRef="USD" decimals="-5">-74200000.0</us-gaap:StockholdersEquity>
```

for example; consider these two context; `ids` needs to be unique with respect to their content(With respect to `period` `entity`; and `entity` with its sub elements; `identifier` and `segment` if present)

 we will use its `id` to map financial facts. Here in example `AssetsCurrent` refers to unit--> whose `id` is `USD` and context information--> whose id is `BalanceAsOf_20120531`; and detail of this this context id can be found in `context` element.
here everything should be unique other wise it will create duplicate facts/contexts.
You can see here that; both context has same period but so why can't their `ids`? because one context has addition detail `segment` information.
(i am not going in detail here; if you want to know; how it is detecting duplicate/error consider example no 25 and 26 from the link.)

in other way you can also view facts/values with three axis as `CIK` `period` and `xmlname`;and this uniqueness makes them comparing with other company's facts with these axis.

Comment: Are you using .NET? If so, Gepsio (gepsio.codeplex.com) could help with the parsing.

Comment: @JoeCoderGuy: If you go down the the page which i have given; explanations are given about everything(`id`, `xbrli:startDate`, ..`endDate`.. )example: `Example no: 25` from that link.

Answer (score 6):

Don't rely on the value of the `contextRef` attribute. The EDGAR FIler Manual gives advice to filers about creating mnemonic values, but all the software used to create filings uses their own ways of creating these values.

All the `contextRef` is good for is locating the `context` for a particular fact. It is the parts of the `context` that organize the data.